# powershell multi valued variables or sql table

Tags: sql, powershell, psobject

i'm wanting to write data into memory only for a temp time. the format is essentially the same as an sql table with say 5 columns and 1,000 rows, give or take. simply i want to store this data and run queries against it to make calculations, sorting it, querying it to then produce chart reports and excel data.

I looked at custom psobjects and then sql and i can't see why i'd use custom psobjects over sql, what do you think?

I also couldn't see that adding multiple rows as such, using psobjects was as straight forward as adding another row in sql.

thanks
steve

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you're more comfortable with, but if you're going to do it in Powershell then using PS custom objects seems like a logical choice since the cmdlets were designed to work with those.